# Mysql where clause query on json column has array value

Tags: mysql, database, where-clause

I have following records in my DB.

```
table= defense

id   Atype
1   {"Domain_name":www.pgmobile.com , "attack": true, "probability": "9.53"}
2   {"Domain_name":www.fb.com , "attack": false , "probability": "3.35"}
3   {"Domain_name":www.pub.com , "attack": true, "probability": "8.34"}
```

I want to make where clause condition on Atype column. Where in column Atype  attack is  true...

e.g: select * from defense where  **attack= true**     // here some help needed

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For {"Domain_Name": ["www.fb.com"], "attack": [false], "Probability": [0.001]}

query wil be use 'like'

```
SELECT *
FROM defense
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(Atype, '$.attack') LIKE '[false]';
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `Atype` is defined as JSON in your table, you can use this query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM defense
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(Atype, '$.attack') = true;
```

as you can see from this [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/geoYmuBW4ZYBtzH527WQC2/4)

Comment: Atype is defined as VARCHAR.

Comment: I see it works with VARCHAR too. I updated the DBFiddel. :)

Comment: Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_extract: "Invalid value."  Getting this error.

Comment: Did you find a corrispondence between your table definition and data insert with my DBFiddle? Which version of Mysql are you using?

Comment: what if data in column is like this

 {"Domain_Name": ["www.fb.com"], "attack": [false], "Probability": [0.001]}